# What happened to the Cross Particles stolen by Mitch Carson?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-2015

I re-watched *Ant-Man* last night and noticed something I hadn't either picked up on before or paid much attention to. Amidst the hubbub and fighting after Scott breaks out and Hank gets shot, Mitch Carson retrieves a vial of Cross Particles from the dead worker. He then escapes and as far as I can tell he isn't seen again in the film.

This is interesting because Mitch was quite desperate to get his hands on Pym Particles, we see some of this play out in the opening scene and Hank spells it out later on.

> **Hank Pym:** This isn’t the first time these guys have tried to get their hands on game changing weaponry. That’s Mitchell Carson, ex-head of defense at SHIELD, presently in the business of toppling governments. He always wanted my tech, and now, unless we break in and steal the Yellowjacket and destroy all the data, Darren Cross is gonna unleash chaos upon the world.
>
> <sub>*Ant-Man*</sub>

So, Mitch getting away with the Cross Particles is quite an important thing as he is sure to do something with them. However, it doesn't seem like we've seen anything related to this since, at least in connection to Ant-Man.

I know there is the upcoming film, *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*, but I want to know **do we know of anything that has come of Mitch taking these particles so far?** Do any of the tie in comics cover this or the TV shows? Or have I completely missed something in the films where this was shown?

Comment: Well, Carson's appearance in MCU was just once as far as I remember. Nothing is mentioned in the *Ant-Man and the Wasp: The Prelude* (its just the summary of the first movie). My honest guess is that the writers simply forgot about Carson.

Comment: Also, Carson would need the equipment to use the particles (Pym or Cross), which was all destroyed when the building imploded. So I guess Carson just disposed of the particles as he had no use of it (?) *maybe*

Comment: @Shreedhar I wouldn't have thought he'd dispose of the particles, else I doubt he'd steal them in the first place and certainly not if he heard of the Yellowjacket v Ant-Man fight which proves they work. Presumably though it's not been mentioned because he's trying to figure out how to get them to work, i.e. he needs the suit. If he's ever going to come back that is.

Comment: "the writers simply forgot about Carson" — or they put/left it in there as a possible jumping off point for future stories, but decided they didn't want to follow it up.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yeah. it's just a guess. But when h stole the vial, he didn't know what was going to happen (the lab imploding, Cross dying etc.). Anyways, although this is a really good question, I'm disappointed that we may never find out the answer. Would be great if the third movie uses this as the start point to a major plot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing seems to have been shown of the Cross Particles that Mitch took so far. Interestingly though there was an ending, presumably post-credits scene, filmed for *Ant-Man* that included Scott tracking down Mitch and recovering the Cross Particles.

> At the end of the movie he gets away and has these Cross particles, and there was a sequence where Ant-Man has an encounter with him. But then for a couple reasons, it felt like maybe we should leave those particles out there. In that original thing, he took Martin Donovan out and got the particles.
>
> <sub>[Cinema Blend, Ant-Man Ending: What Was Originally Going To Happen](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Ant-Man-Ending-What-Was-Originally-Going-Happen-72683.html)</sub>

Here Peyton Reed explains that they left them out on purpose. Of course part of this would also seem to do with the last and post-credits scenes tying into *Captain America: Civil War*. Another reason they scrapped it is explained by Peyton in a later interview he did for *Ant-Man and the Wasp*:

> We shot a thing for the first Ant-Man that we eventually cut from the movie, which was a Mitchell Carson scene, because originally he got blown up in the Pym Tech implosion, and survived it, and was scarred. And then we had a thing sort of at the end where he was behind a desk at a hotel room or whatever, and a man was coming to take him out. And we actually shot that. And we shot it when poor Martin Donovan had Sciatica. He had serious back issues, so we didn't end up using it.
>
> <sub>[Cinema Blend,
> Ant-Man Left An Important Storyline Open, And The Director Really Wants To Go Back And Address It](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2458903/ant-man-left-an-important-storyline-open-and-the-director-really-wants-to-go-back-and-address-it)</sub>

In this interview he also talks about whether they were going to address it in *Ant-Man and the Wasp* or not but decided against it. He concludes the statement by saying *"But it's still out there!"* so we can be sure there's still potential for this to come back around even if it doesn't seem to have done so yet. Especially so as it was a a deliberate choice to leave out the scene and so leave the Cross Particles out there somewhere.

> It's certainly something we talked about, because it was this dangling thing from the first movie: there are some Cross Tech particles out there. So we talked for a long time about whether we were going to actively pursue it in this movie, and we eventually sort of felt like, 'I don't feel like we want to double back and deal with that thing if it's not germane to the plot of this movie.' But it's still out there!
>
> <sub>[Cinema Blend,
> Ant-Man Left An Important Storyline Open, And The Director Really Wants To Go Back And Address It](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2458903/ant-man-left-an-important-storyline-open-and-the-director-really-wants-to-go-back-and-address-it)</sub>

Presumably, unless the story takes them elsewhere, this is going to be revisited at some point down the line.

Comment: Mitch is probably having a beer with [Samuel Sterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_(comics)#Film) right now.